# EclipseLink: Joins in @AdditionalCriteria definitions

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a simple EclipseLink data model with 3 entities:

User <-> Privilege <-> Document

Privilege has one bidirectional ManyToOne relation to User and one to Document

I'd like to make sure that each user can only access documents when he has the READ privilege. My first idea was to use the @AdditionalCriteria annotation and add the user_id property to the EntityManager:

```
@AdditionalCriteria("this.privileges.type='READ' AND this.privileges.user.id=:user_id") 
public class Document { ... }
```

However, this fails:
'this.privileges.type' is not a valid type. 
'this.privileges.user.id' is not a valid type.

Comment: It won't work anyway, as how are you going to pass in the user id parameter?  Filtering results is not recommended, as it prevents any sort of caching.  For instance, what do you expect to see if your application does a simple 'find' call for a specific document?  Instead of using additional criteria to force your queries to not work, you should instead use queries that directly - add the "d.privileges.type='READ' AND d.privileges.user.id=:user_id" clause to queries and enforce the application can only use those by passing in the current user id.

Comment: old question, but this might be doable using not AdditionalCriteria but multitenancy, you can specify multiple discriminator columns and they can be from secondary table